# private method called noMethodError ruby

Tags: ruby

I've been trying to work the following problem out and ran into the error. The point of the problem is to use a given key sequence to encrypt a string. For example, when given "cat" and [1,2,3] the result should be "dcw" 
Any suggestions? the error was the following

```
def vigenere_cipher(string, key_sequence)
  keyIndex=0
  string=string.each_char.map do |c|
    c=c.shift!(c,keyIndex)
    keyIndex+=1
    if keyIndex=key_sequence.length
      keyIndex=0
    end
  end
  return string
end

def shift!(c,keyIndex)
  alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
  inititalLetterIndex=alphabet.index(c)
  finalLetterIndex=alphabet[inititalLetterIndex+keyIndex]
  return alphabet[finalLetterIndex]
end

vigenere_cipher("cat", [1,2,3])
# private method `shift!' called for "c":String (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: `c` is a string (a single character). There is no method `String#shift!`.

Comment: Try `'cat'.chars.zip([1,2,3]).map { |c,i| (c.ord+i).chr }.join #=> "dcw"`.

Comment: but I define the shift! method...sorry I am new to this. Why does my defined shift! method not work?

Comment: @JonathanMath : You are defining `shift!` on the top level. Doing this, it becomes a private method of class Object. Since you invoke it as `c.shift!` and `c` is of type `String` and `String` inherits from `Object`, you get this error message. If you define a method on top level, you have to call it without explicit receiver. If you want to call it with an instance of type String as a receiver (which in your case would not make much sense), you have to define it within class `String`.

Comment: My comment is correct, but I somehow missed that you had defined a method `shift!`. `c.shift!` means the instance method `:shift!` is being sent to its receiver, `c`. Since `c` is an instance of the class `String`, `:shift!` must be an instance method of `String` (meaning that it was defined in `String` or in one of its ancestors). Try this: `c.methods.include?(:shift!) #=> false`.

Comment: When you posted your comment that was directed to me, you needed to start it like so: `@CarySwoveland,...`. (`Cary` preceded by an ampersand will also work.) That way, SO will inform me that a comment has been left for me. If you don't do that the person you are addressing may never see the comment.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : Your code looks good. It doesn't cycle the key, and wouldn't work with `'z'+1` though.

Comment: @Eric, I mulled that, but since there's no mention that 'a' "follows" 'z' or that offsets are non-negative, I assumed that negative offsets would be used to map characters to earlier ones in the alphabet (e.g., `'z' -> ('a'.ord-25).chr #=> 'a'`. I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call `shift!` on string object that does not define on `String` Class, instead you defined on main object. You can call it like `shift!(c,keyIndex)` instead of `c.shift!(c,keyIndex)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call you method `shift!` on a string, you will have to define it on `String` class.

```
class String
  def shift!(keyIndex)
    # you can access `c` using `self` here
    ...
  end
end
```

Then you can call it as `c.shift!(keyIndex)` (Note the arguments are different).

Answer (score 1):

## Step 1

```
cipher.rb:4:in `block in vigenere_cipher': private method `shift!' called for "c":String (NoMethodError)
```

`shift!` isn't defined in String class, but at the top level.
So replace `c=c.shift!(c,keyIndex)` by `c=shift!(c,keyIndex)`

## Step 2

```
cipher.rb:17:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

Line 16 defines :

```
finalLetterIndex=alphabet[inititalLetterIndex+keyIndex]
```

alphabet contains letters as Strings, so `finalLetterIndex` isn't an index (Numeric), but a String.

On line 17, you try to use this String as an index.

Replace line 16 with :

```
finalLetterIndex=inititalLetterIndex+keyIndex
```

## Step 3

Your script doesn't raise any exception anymore. It also doesn't display anything, so add a puts to the last line :

```
puts vigenere_cipher("cat", [1,2,3]).inspect
```

It returns :

```
[0, 0, 0]
```

## Step 4

`keyIndex` seems to be stuck at 0. Why?
Look at line 6 :

```
if keyIndex=key_sequence.length
```

It doesn't test an equality, it assigns `keyIndex` to `key_sequence.length`.
Since any number is truthy in Ruby, it executes the code inside the if statement. Replace with

```
if keyIndex==key_sequence.length
```

## Step 5

Your code returns `[nil, nil, 0]`. Why?

`string` is defined as the result of `map`. `map` returns an Array, in which each element is the result of the last executed command inside the block : in this case, the `if` statement.

`if` returns `nil` when the condition isn't satisfied, and returns the last executed command otherwise. In this case `0`.

Add `c` at the last line of your `map` block.

## Step 6

Your code now returns `["c", "b", "v"]`. Why?

You only shift by `shiftIndex`, not by the amount defined in `key_sequence` Array. Replace

```
c=shift!(c,keyIndex)
```

with

```
c=shift!(c,key_sequence[keyIndex])
```

## Step 7

Your code returns `["d", "c", "w"]`. Almost there!

Ruby is a dynamic language. You're free to overwrite the String `string` with an Array, but it will confuse others and your future self.

Use `array` or `letters` instead of `string`, and return `letters.join`

Your script now returns `"dcw"`.

It should look like :

```
def vigenere_cipher(string, key_sequence)
  keyIndex=0
  letters=string.each_char.map do |c|
    c=shift!(c,key_sequence[keyIndex])
    keyIndex+=1
    if keyIndex==key_sequence.length
      keyIndex=0
    end
    c
  end
  return letters.join
end

def shift!(c,keyIndex)
  alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
  inititalLetterIndex=alphabet.index(c)
  finalLetterIndex=inititalLetterIndex+keyIndex
  return alphabet[finalLetterIndex]
end
```

## Step 8

`vigenere_cipher("Hello", [1,2,3])`

raises

`cipher.rb:17:in 'shift!': undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`.

Well, 'H' isn't found in your alphabet. Use downcase :

```
array=string.downcase.each_char.map do |c|
```

## Step 9

```
vigenere_cipher("Hello World", [1,2,3])
```

doesn't work either, because of the space. Delete anything that isn't a letter :

```
array=string.downcase.delete('^a-z').each_char.map do |c|
```

## Step 10

```
vigenere_cipher("zzz", [1,2,3])
```

returns an empty String, because there's no letter after `z`.

Use modulo 26 :

```
return alphabet[finalLetterIndex%26]
```

## Step 11

Remove typos, don't use camelCase for variables, remove unnecessary `return` and you get :

```
def vigenere_cipher(string, key_sequence)
  key_index = 0
  letters = string.downcase.delete('^a-z').each_char.map do |c|
    c = shift(c, key_sequence[key_index])
    key_index = (key_index + 1) % key_sequence.length
    c
  end
  letters.join
end

def shift(c, key_index)
  alphabet = ('a'..'z').to_a
  initial_letter_index = alphabet.index(c)
  final_letter_index = initial_letter_index + key_index
  alphabet[final_letter_index % 26]
end
```

## Step 12

Using `each_char`, `zip` and `cycle`, I'd rewrite the whole code this way :

```
class Integer
  # 0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', ..., 25 => 'z', 26 => 'a'
  def to_letter
    ('a'.ord + self % 26).chr
  end
end

class String
  # 'A' => '0', 'a' => 0, ..., 'z' => 25
  def to_code
    self.downcase.ord - 'a'.ord
  end
end

def vigenere_cipher(string, key)
  short_string = string.delete('^A-Za-z')
  short_string.each_char.zip(key.cycle).map do |char, shift|
    (char.to_code + shift).to_letter
  end.join
end
```

## Step 13

Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) uses a String as key :

```
def vigenere_cipher(string, key)
  short_string = string.delete('^A-Za-z')
  short_string.each_char.zip(key.each_char.cycle).map do |char, shift|
    (char.to_code + shift.to_code).to_letter
  end.join
end

vigenere_cipher('Attack at dawn!', 'LEMON').upcase # => "LXFOPVEFRNHR"
```

## Step 14

You should also be able to decrypt the message :

```
def vigenere_cipher(string, key, decrypt = false)
  short_string = string.delete('^A-Za-z')
  short_string.each_char.zip(key.each_char.cycle).map do |char, shift|
    (char.to_code + shift.to_code * (decrypt ? -1 : 1)).to_letter
  end.join
end

vigenere_cipher("LXFOPVEFRNHR", 'LEMON', :decrypt) #=> "attackatdawn"
```

Well, that was longer than expected! :D

Comment: Regarding  Step 10, where does it say that 'z' with an offset of 1 maps to 'a'? I would argue that `vigenere_cipher("zzz", [1,2,3])` is invalid, that `vigenere_cipher("zzz", [-25,-24,-,23]) #> 'abc'`is needed to produce the desired mapping.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : For historical reasons mostly. See Wikipedia article : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher. This cipher was defined long before ASCII tables. Every operation is done modulo 26.

Comment: Being unaware of the "Vigenere", I assumed the method name was the OP's invention. Naturally, I suspected that cipher was the OP's intent, but I was going on a literal interpretation of the question.

Comment: Well, here it is! My answer with the worst return on investment! :)

Comment: Who said SO isn't fickle?