# How to implement Caesar Cipher in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm learning Ruby on [theOdinProject](http://theodinproject.com/) and I need to build the Caeser Cipher. Here's my code:

```
    def caesar_cipher plaintext, factor
    codepoints_array = []
    ciphertext = ""

    plaintext.split('').each do |letter|
        if letter =~ /[^a-zA-Z]/
            codepoints_array << letter.bytes.join('').to_i
        else
            codepoints_array << letter.bytes.join('').to_i + factor
        end
    end
    ciphertext = codepoints_array.pack 'C*'
    puts ciphertext
end
caesar_cipher("What a string!", 5)
```

I bet it's not really "elegant" but the main issue here is that the output should be "Bmfy f xywnsl!" but what do I have is "\mfy f xywnsl!". I've been struggling with this task for a couple of days now, but I still have no idea how to "chain" the alphabet so 'z' becomes 'a' with the factor == 1.

I could check the finished tasks of the other people on theOdinProject but their code usually different/more professional and I tried to get a hint, not the final solution. I'll be really thankful if someone could hint me how to resolve this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: Have a look at a [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and investigate what char (by its number) you get when you add for example the factor `5` to the bytes of an `W`. Than look how you need to change the byte vale to get the expected character...

Comment: `ord` does the same as `bytes.join('').to_i`

Comment: `'a'.upto('z').cycle.first(52)` is the alphabet twice. See [Array#cycle](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-cycle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Hints

Your code would almost work fine if the [ASCII table](http://ascii.cl/) had only 26 characters.

But `W` is not `w`, and after `z` comes `{`, not `a`.

So you first need to apply [downcase](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-downcase) to your letters, offset the bytecode so that `a` is 0, and do every calculation [modulo](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Numeric.html#method-i-25) 26.

## Modified version

```
def caesar_cipher plaintext, factor
  codepoints_array = []
  ciphertext = ""

  a_codepoint = 'a'.ord

  plaintext.split('').each do |letter|
    if letter =~ /[^a-zA-Z]/
      codepoints_array << letter.bytes.join('').to_i
    else
      shifted_codepoint = letter.downcase.bytes.join('').to_i + factor
      codepoints_array << (shifted_codepoint - a_codepoint) % 26 + a_codepoint
    end
  end
  ciphertext = codepoints_array.pack 'C*'
  ciphertext
end

puts caesar_cipher("What a string!", 5) #=> "bmfy f xywnsl!"
```

## Another solution

I wrote a small Ruby script for [Vigenere chiper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41160531/6419007) a while ago. Caesar cipher is just a variant of it, with the same factor for every character :

```
class Integer
  # 0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', ..., 25 => 'z', 26 => 'a'
  def to_letter
    ('a'.ord + self % 26).chr
  end
end

class String
  # 'A' => '0', 'a' => 0, ..., 'z' => 25
  def to_code
    self.downcase.ord - 'a'.ord
  end
end

def caesar_cipher(string, factor)
  short_string = string.delete('^A-Za-z')
  short_string.each_char.map do |char|
    (char.to_code + factor).to_letter
  end.join
end

puts caesar_cipher("What a string!", 5) #=> "bmfyfxywnsl"
puts caesar_cipher("bmfyfxywnsl", -5)   #=> "whatastring"
```

With ciphers, it is recommended to remove any punctuation sign or whitespace, because they make it much easier to decode the string with statistical analysis.

Caesar cipher is very weak anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Good thing I understand your code. Bad thing I would probably never come up with this idea. Any ideas on how to keep the same case? (because it's part of the task - I should have clarified this earlier I think :) )

Comment: In Ruby, there's always a 100 ways to write the same piece of code. See TIMTOADY (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) . Here's another way, which keeps the case : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338764/ruby-caesar-cipher-explanation Note that it's a very bad idea for a cipher to keep spaces and case.