# Ruby Caesar Cipher Explanation

Tags: ruby

This code works perfectly, but can anybody explains this how? I am new to the Ruby programming.
Here is the code:

```
def caesar_cipher (string, number)
    caesar_string = ""

    string.scan (/./) do |i|
      if ("a".."z").include? (i.downcase) # Identify letters only.
        number.times {i = i.next}
      end
      caesar_string << i[-1]
    end
    return caesar_string


  end


  print "What would you like to encrypt?"
  text = gets.chomp

  puts caesar_cipher( text, 5 )
```

Comment: Which part do you not understand?

Comment: A better way is `string.gsub(/[a-z]/i){|s| (s.ord + number).chr}`.

Comment: @sawa. Your "better" way has the disadvantage of not looping from 'z' to 'a' again. `W` + 5 is `B` in the above code, it becomes `\\` with your code.

Comment: You are probably right. In that case, the OP can play around with some modulo operations (`%`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Initialize an empty string:

   `caesar_string = ""`
2. Iterate over each character in the string (note that `string.each_char` would be preferred nowadays):

   `string.scan (/./) do |i|`

   Note that all Ruby style guides discourage the space between the method call and the opening parenthesis.
3. For each letter, check if its lowercase form is in the range from "a" to "z".

   `if ("a".."z").include? (i.downcase)`

   Note that defining that range outside the loop (i.e. `LOWERCASE_LETTERS = ("a"..."z")` would be better, since it avoids generating a throwaway range object on every iteration).
4. Shift the letter `number` times:

   `number.times {i = i.next}`

   This works because `"a".next == "b"` The same could have been achieved with something like `(i.ord + number).chr` though without all the iterations.
5. The character is added to the previously initialized `caesar_string`.

   `caesar_string << i[-1]`

   The author is only using the last character of the string (`[-1]`) since `"z".next == "aa"`.
6. The string is returned.

   `return caesar_string`

   Note that the use of `return` here is both unnecessary and not idiomatic.

Comment: That was extremely helpful! Thank you!

Comment: point 5 is because `'z'.next #=> 'aa'` etc

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. :)

Comment: `(i.ord + number).chr` runs out of alphabet if i is toward the end("z" for instance) and number is large enough(say 3).

Comment: @seph Yeah, that's why I said "something like". ;-) If you go over 122, you have to use `(97 + sum % 122).chr`.

Answer (score 2):

```
string.scan (/./)
```

will create and array of each character in the string and then iterate over each character.

```
if ("a".."z").include? (i.downcase)
```

The above statement uses a `Range` to create an array of letters of the alphabet and allows the method to only shift characters of the alphabet and skip numbers and punctuation characters that shouldn't be shifted.

```
number.times {i = i.next}
```

This shifts the letter 5 times to the right. However, If the `i` is `"z"` the `i.next` will return `"ae"` so the next line

```
caesar_string << i[-1]
```

takes only the last character in the string and cuts off the "a" in this edge case.

On most cases `i` will be a single character and [-1] is the only character so it works for both cases. The `<<` operator shovels the character onto the end of `caesar_string` to rebuild the string one character at a time.

```
return caesar_string
```

When the `string.scan (/./) do |i|` block has finished, the `caesar_string` is returned.